# Vector member variable of class does not remain same after push_back across two different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdvector

I am attempting multithreaded coding in Visual Studio C++ as follows. The actual project is bigger and the smallest verifiable program/design demonstrating the problem is depicted below.

`class vec_of_foo_c{}` has a private `std::vector<type> vec;`

`type` above is `struct foo_s{int a;};`

`vec_of_foo_c` has member function `void add_to_vector1()` that will be called from `thread1` and member function `void add_to_vector2()` that will be called from `thread2`. Each of these member function's job is to simply create an object of `foo_s` and `push_back` into `vec`. Since the threads may access `vec` at different times, prior to `push_back` I lock a `mutex` and it gets released once it goes out of scope.

Now, `thread1` will be defined as a member function of an object of `class call_function1_from_here` and `thread2` will be defined as a member function of an object of `class call_function2_from_here`.

The following code expresses the above in code that compiles and runs just fine.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

typedef class call_function1_from_here_c  call_function1_from_here;
typedef class call_function2_from_here_c  call_function2_from_here;

struct foo_s {
    int a;
};

class vec_of_foo_c {//This class contains member function maincall() that calls public member functions of objects of type call_function1_from_here and call_function2_from_here
public:
    void maincall(call_function1_from_here&, call_function2_from_here&);
    void add_to_vector1();
    void add_to_vector2();
    int size() { return static_cast<int>(vec.size()); }
private:
    std::vector<foo_s> vec;
    static std::mutex mMutex;
};

std::mutex vec_of_foo_c::mMutex;//Private static member specification outside of main() scope.

class call_function1_from_here_c {
public:
    void add_foo_1(vec_of_foo_c&);
};

class call_function2_from_here_c {
public:
    void add_foo_2(vec_of_foo_c&);
};

void call_function1_from_here_c::add_foo_1(vec_of_foo_c& vec_of_foo) {
    vec_of_foo.add_to_vector1();
}

void call_function2_from_here_c::add_foo_2(vec_of_foo_c& vec_of_foo) {
    vec_of_foo.add_to_vector2();
}

void vec_of_foo_c::add_to_vector1() {
    printf("Address of vec is %x\n", &vec);//This address is different
    foo_s foo;
    foo.a = 1;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
    printf("%d\n", 1);
    vec.push_back(foo);
}

void vec_of_foo_c::add_to_vector2() {
    printf("Address of vec is %x\n", &vec);//This address is different      
    foo_s foo;
    foo.a = 2;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
    printf("%d\n", 2);
    vec.push_back(foo);
}

void vec_of_foo_c::maincall(call_function1_from_here_c& cf1fh, call_function2_from_here_c& cf2fh) {
    printf("Address of vec is %x\n", &vec);//This address is different
    std::thread t1{ &call_function1_from_here_c::add_foo_1, &cf1fh, *this};
    std::thread t2{ &call_function2_from_here_c::add_foo_2, &cf2fh, *this };
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    printf("Size of vector is %d\n", size());//!!At this point, why is the size 0??!!
    _getwch();
}

int main() {
    vec_of_foo_c vec_of_foo;
    call_function1_from_here_c cf1fh;
    call_function2_from_here_c cf2fh;
    vec_of_foo.maincall(cf1fh, cf2fh);
}
```

However, despite the `push_back`s, the size of the vector still shows 0 within `class vec_of_foo_c`'s scope. I would expect that the size should show 2.

On delving further, it appears that `&vec` (address of `vec`) is different in `maincall()`, `add_to_vector1()` and `add_to_vector2()` although these are all member functions of the same class. This is quite surprising for me since I am passing all objects as reference.

In the framework above, how should one go about correct `push_back` into a common `std::vector` across multiple threads?

Comment: Print the value of `this` as well as that of `&vec`. Then read the "Notes" section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread).

Comment: @molbdnilo `this` is also different. I am quite surprised at this since member functions `add_foo_1` and `add_foo_2` take their argument as reference.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, wrapping it in `std::ref` did the trick! Thanks.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Are `std::ref(*this)` and `this` completely equivalent?